# js flat array to multi-level array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
[{
iStatusId: 4,
vStatus: "Under Preparation",
iJobType: 1,
bIsActive: true,
iOrder: 2
},
{
iStatusId: 5,
vStatus: "Stamp & Signatures by Client",
iJobType: 1,
bIsActive: true,
iOrder: 3
},
{
iStatusId: 7,
vStatus: "CA & CE Certification",
iJobType: 1,
bIsActive: true,
iOrder: 6
},
{
iStatusId: 8,
vStatus: "Application Submission Date",
iJobType: 1,
bIsActive: true,
iOrder: 4
},
{
iStatusId: 9,
vStatus: "File in HQ-BRU/Tech ",
iJobType: 1,
bIsActive: true,
iOrder: 7
}]
```

And I need it like this:

```
[{iJobType: 1, data:
{
iStatusId: 4,
vStatus: "Under Preparation",
bIsActive: true,
iOrder: 2
},
{
iStatusId: 5,
vStatus: "Stamp & Signatures by Client",
bIsActive: true,
iOrder: 3
},
{
iStatusId: 7,
vStatus: "CA & CE Certification",
bIsActive: true,
iOrder: 6
},
{
iStatusId: 8,
vStatus: "Application Submission Date",
bIsActive: true,
iOrder: 4
},
{
iStatusId: 9,
vStatus: "File in HQ-BRU/Tech ",
verification",
bIsActive: true,
iOrder: 7
}]
```

Please help.

Earlier I wrote a function to convert flat navigation array to a tree, but that does not help here.

```
$scope.navConvert = function(array) {
    var map = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var obj = array[i];
        obj.items = [];

        map[obj.NavId] = obj;

        var parent = obj.NavParent || '-';
        if (!map[parent]) {
            map[parent] = {
                items: []
            };
        }
        map[parent].items.push(obj);
    }
    return map['-'].items;
}
```

So, I'm looking for a fresh direction.

Comment: There are no multi level arrays here.

Comment: @Vld, you are right. Possibly I am not being able to put the words in properly here.

Comment: Do you need to group them by iJobType property?

Comment: Right @Bommox but no summary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a hash table as reference for the value of `iJobType` and build an array upon of this.

```js
var data = [{ iStatusId: 4, vStatus: "Under Preparation", iJobType: 1, bIsActive: true, iOrder: 2 }, { iStatusId: 5, vStatus: "Stamp & Signatures by Client", iJobType: 1, bIsActive: true, iOrder: 3 }, { iStatusId: 7, vStatus: "CA & CE Certification", iJobType: 1, bIsActive: true, iOrder: 6 }, { iStatusId: 8, vStatus: "Application Submission Date", iJobType: 1, bIsActive: true, iOrder: 4 }, { iStatusId: 9, vStatus: "File in HQ-BRU/Tech ", iJobType: 1, bIsActive: true, iOrder: 7 }],
    grouped = [];

data.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!this[a.iJobType]) {
        this[a.iJobType] = { iJobType: a.iJobType, data: [] };
        grouped.push(this[a.iJobType]);
    }
    this[a.iJobType].data.push({
        iStatusId: a.iStatusId,
        vStatus: a.vStatus,
        bIsActive: a.bIsActive,
        iOrder: a.iOrder
    });
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Good thinking to display the console at max height.

Answer (score 1):

If the requirement is for searching or filtering purpose, changing the structure of the data is not required.
You can use the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to obtain the elements having a given iJobType value:

```
var arr = [{
iStatusId: 4,
vStatus: "Under Preparation",
iJobType: 1,
bIsActive: true,
iOrder: 2
},
{
iStatusId: 5,
vStatus: "Stamp & Signatures by Client",
iJobType: 1,
bIsActive: true,
iOrder: 3
},
{
iStatusId: 7,
vStatus: "CA & CE Certification",
iJobType: 1,
bIsActive: true,
iOrder: 6
},
{
iStatusId: 8,
vStatus: "Application Submission Date",
iJobType: 1,
bIsActive: true,
iOrder: 4
},
{
iStatusId: 9,
vStatus: "File in HQ-BRU/Tech ",
iJobType: 1,
bIsActive: true,
iOrder: 7
}];
arr

//1. define the filter function
function filterByJobType(value){
  //this.filterValue will be passed as a parameter in the filter execution
  return value.iJobType == this.jobTypeFilter
}

//2. res is the subset of elements from arr fullfilling the filter condition
var res = arr.filter(filterByJobType, {jobTypeFilter: 1 })
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple function to create the new data array

```
var data = [{
        iStatusId: 4,
        vStatus: "Under Preparation",
        iJobType: 1,
        bIsActive: true,
        iOrder: 2
    },
    {
        iStatusId: 5,
        vStatus: "Stamp & Signatures by Client",
        iJobType: 1,
        bIsActive: true,
        iOrder: 3
    }
]   
var newData = []
for (var i in data) {
    var tempObj = {iJobType: data[i].iJobType, data: data[i]};
    delete tempObj.data.iJobType;
    newData.push(tempObj)
}
```

Output:

```
[{
    iJobType: 1,
        data: {
            iStatusId: 4,
            vStatus: "Under Preparation",
            bIsActive: true,
            iOrder: 2
        }
    },
    {
        iJobType: 1,
        data: {
            iStatusId: 5,
            vStatus: "Stamp & Signatures by Client",
            bIsActive: true,
            iOrder: 3
        }
    }
]
```